# Retrieve mRNA sequence based on DNA coordinates

Tags: coordinates, bioinformatics, genome

I have a list of genome DNA coordinates (hg38), I want to retrieve corresponding mRNA sequence 200bp up/downstream of these coordinates’ positions, and idea?

Thank you.

I have tried table browser, easy to get all codon sequence based on coordinates, but I don't know where to set the parameter of 200 bp up/down stream of those coordinates.

Comment: If you do not get an answer you want quickly on this stack, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bedtools getfasta`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html). Change the input coordinates to bed format, and use any scripting tool to increase the interval by 200 nt in both directions. From the docs:

```
$ cat test.fa
>chr1
AAAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCGCTACTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG

$ cat test.bed
chr1 5 10

$ bedtools getfasta -fi test.fa -bed test.bed
>chr1:5-10
AAACC

# optionally write to an output file
$ bedtools getfasta -fi test.fa -bed test.bed -fo test.fa.out

$ cat test.fa.out
>chr1:5-10
AAACC
```

You can install `bedtools`, for example, using `conda`:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name your_env_name bedtools
```

**REFERENCES:**

`conda`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html
`conda create`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html

Comment: Alternative to writing a script, [bedtools slop](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/slop.html) can also be used to expand the intervals.